# Не работает zoom камеры на iOS

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

После обновления iOS до версии 14.0 рабочий код по zoom камеры по жестам перестал работать. Управление осуществляется камерой запускаемой ARKit. Никаких ошибок не возникает. Код привожу ниже:

```
@objc public func zoom(pinch: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
      guard let device = backCamera else {return}
        
      func minMaxZoom(_ factor: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return min(max(factor, 1.0), device.activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor)
      }

      func update(scale factor: CGFloat) {
        do {
          try device.lockForConfiguration()
            defer { device.unlockForConfiguration() }
            device.videoZoomFactor = factor
            print("DEBUG \(device.videoZoomFactor)")
        } catch {
          debugPrint(error)
        }
      }

      let newScaleFactor = minMaxZoom(pinch.scale * zoomFactor)

      switch pinch.state {
        case .began: fallthrough
        case .changed: update(scale: newScaleFactor)
            print("NEW \(device.videoZoomFactor)")
        case .ended:
          zoomFactor = minMaxZoom(newScaleFactor)
          update(scale: zoomFactor)
            print("NEW \(device.videoZoomFactor)")
        default: break
      }
    }
```

Заметил что при выводе в консоль значения device.videoZoomFactor после присвоения ему значения, оно не меняется. Сломал всю голову как это исправить на версиях 13.+ все работало отлично!

Answer (score 0):

Для изменения zoom видео используйте метод:

[ramp(toVideoZoomFactor:withRate:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624614-ramp)

Comment: Использовал, по прежнему ничего, событие срабатывает но zoom нет

Comment: @АлинаБорисова а сам расчётный `zoomFactor = minMaxZoom(newScaleFactor)` правильный получается?

Comment: Да, вывод в консоль показывает изменение числа zoomFactor